# Mail settings configuration file (mobileconfig alternative)

Tags: android

iOS have a good configuration file called .mobileconfig that i use for mail settings. I just download the file and the phone fix the rest, i have searched for android alternatives but i cant find any. So my question is have android something similar ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this as well.

I don't think it does... but in android, you have a lot more freedom to have an app make those changes, if I understand things correctly.